# How to get Theme type (Typescript) from react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a hook `useThemeStyled` to get the react-navigation theme in my styles with React-Native.

```
import { useTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { Theme } from "@react-navigation/native/lib/typescript/src/types";

export const HomeScreen = () => {
  const sylings = useThemeStyled(styles);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={sylings.title}>HomeScreen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = (theme: Theme) => ({
  title: {
    color: theme.colors.text
  }
});

const useThemeStyled = (style: (theme: Theme) => any) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return StyleSheet.create(style(theme));
};
```

Is the `import { Theme } from "@react-navigation/native/lib/typescript/src/types";` correct?

Is there a way to not have to define `:Theme` type for the theme parameter when declaring `const styles ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `typeof`

```js
type Theme = typeof DefaultTheme;
```